# How can I modify a Bootstrap form so that some fields are aligned on the left side of the screen, while other fields are aligned on the right side?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I want to make a form that adheres to design specifics that require me to align some fields to the left side of the viewport, and other fields that align to the right side. Here is what I have so far:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h2>Order Entry</h2>
        <label for="ipt_authNum">Authorization Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ipt_authNum" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ipt_customer">Customer</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="ipt_customer" style="width:30%;">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ipt_billTo">Bill To</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ipt_billTo" />
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, this block of markup makes a form where the fields are stacked on top of each other. Instead of that, I want the "Customer" and "Bill To" fields (labels included) to be across from each other on the same line (with the labels inline). Note that mobile design considerations are not required for this application; it will be a company intranet type deal where employees are only allowed to access the application via a desktop computer. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, there are many more fields to add to this form. I just wanted to get an idea before I got too far into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap grid system to align labels and fields in the form. Below is the sample form. You can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) for some examples. The important thing is the `row` and `col-md-*` classes applied to the divs for bootstrap grid system to align the form accordingly.

View the below example in full page view to see form layout. Hope this helps.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-inline">
 <h2>Order Entry</h2>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2"><label for="ipt_authNum">Authorization Number</label></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ipt_authNum" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-7">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="ipt_customer">Customer</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="ipt_customer" style="width:30%;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2"><label for="ipt_billTo">Bill To</label></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="ipt_billTo" /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, which browser did you test this in? It looks jumbled in IE 11.

Comment: I used Chrome browser.

Comment: Ah. Okay, thanks. Unfortunately, the only browser allowed at my company is Internet Explorer, which I hate tremendously. By chance, have you tested your solution in IE?

Comment: It works in IE. Click on `Run code snippet` button above and then click on `Full page` link to view the form.

Comment: Hmm... you're right. For some reason, it looks very different when I run it through Visual Studio 2015. Maybe I have some sort of setting turned on/off that is causing it to mess up. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think using one `<div class="form-group">` will work. Like :

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ipt_customer">Customer</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ipt_customer" style="width:30%;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <label for="ipt_billTo">Bill To</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ipt_billTo" />
</div>
```

Maybe add some bootstrap col ?

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="ipt_customer">Customer</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="ipt_customer" style="width:30%;">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <label for="ipt_billTo">Bill To</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ipt_billTo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.form-inline require costume width on the inputs and only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms

You should add col classes to your elements also for better results.